# authorized_key ansible module copied my public keys to authorized keys, but I get my passwordless login doesn't work

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, ansible

I am not able to ssh passwordless to my remote host after I copied my public key using ansible authorized_module.

Let me know if you need to see anything else.

````
[xkadutut@wpas .ssh]$ ls -la
total 4
drwx------. 1 xkadutut staff  30 Dec 22 06:26 .
drwxrwxrwx. 1 xkadutut staff 204 Dec 22 05:40 ..
-rw-------. 1 xkadutut staff 395 Dec 22 06:26 authorized_keys
[xkadutut@wpas .ssh]$ pwd
/export/home/staff/xkadutut/.ssh
[xkadutut@wpas .ssh]$

```
   ansible

bash-4.2$ sudo cat kwaku_authorized_keys.yml
---
- hosts: kwaku
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: set authorized public keys for Kwaku
    authorized_key:
      user: xkadutut
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/export/home/staff/kadutut/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"



After I ran the playbook, I tried to ssh to wpas( remote host), and it still asked me for a password. 



bash-4.2$ ssh xkadutut@wpas-prod
**********************************************************
This system is for authorized users only; system access is
monitored. By using this system you  expressly consent  to
this monitoring. Evidence of  unauthorized access  will be
provided to the appropriate law enforcement agencies.
**********************************************************
xkadutut@wpas-prod's password:
````

Comment: Please edit and include output of `ls -la ~/.ssh` on the target machine, the ansible playbook you're running, aswell as the command you use to connect via `ssh`

Comment: How can I make my above comment looks nicer, and clean? @Panki

Comment: By not writing a comment, and using the button labeled "edit" below the question instead.

Comment: Let me know if you are able to understand it better? @Panki

Comment: It's still missing half of what I asked... did you check that the public key is in `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Yes, the public key from my source machine is authorized_keys from my target machine.

Comment: It is still missing the `ssh` command you use to connect afterwards. Why would you use `sudo` to `cat` the playbook? Did you mess up your permissions?

Comment: I used sudo most of the time, but it is just a habit I have. I also provided the ssh command I used to connect to the remote host

Comment: It's a bad habit and you should stop it. Learn what `sudo` does and when you need it - everything else is a potential security hazard

Comment: Do you add the key to `ssh-agent` ? How do you tell `ssh` where your private key file ist?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your only problem, but it appears that your home directory on the remote system has permissions that are too lenient, and the OpenSSH server may be ignoring your `authorized_keys` file.

```
drwx------. 1 xkadutut staff  30 Dec 22 06:26 .
drwxrwxrwx. 1 xkadutut staff 204 Dec 22 05:40 ..
-rw-------. 1 xkadutut staff 395 Dec 22 06:26 authorized_keys
```

According to this, your home directory (`/export/home/staff/xkadutut`) is world- and group-writable. The OpenSSH server by default will ignore `authorized_keys` in this case. See this passage from [the sshd manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#FILES):

> **~/.ssh/authorized_keys**
> Lists the public keys (DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519, RSA) that can be used for logging in as this user. The format of this file is described above. The content of the file is not highly sensitive, but the recommended permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.

> **If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or replaced by unauthorized users. In this case, sshd will not allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to “no”.**

The fix would be to remove group and world write access from your home directory:

```
chmod go-w /export/home/staff/xkadutut
```